# How can I add headers and format MySQL query output files?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I connect to `mysql` from my Linux shell and use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM students INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/students'.
```

1. Why do I see `\N` at line endings? I want each record in a row, but why do I see the `\N` explicitly printed?
2. How can I print all column headers in the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE exports the result to a rather mysql specific delimited format. \N means a NULL value, not end-of-line.

Run e.g. from a command line:

```
echo 'select * from students' | mysql mydb >/tmp/students
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for SELECT shows you how what options you have when using INTO OUTFILE, but you can't export the headers directly that way. See the comments in that documentation for a hacky way of adding header columns though.